# Linux Mint trigger slowly query on mysql on system booting

Tags: mysql, linux, configuration, debian, linux-mint

My debian-based is booting so slow after I installed MySQL and imported some databases on it. Looking for some statement, I found this one during boot:

```
mysql> show full processlist;
+----+------------------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User             | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State          | Info                                                                 |
+----+------------------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  9 | debian-sys-maint | localhost | NULL | Query   |   12 | Opening tables | select count(*) into @discard from `information_schema`.`PARTITIONS` |
| 10 | root             | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL           | show full processlist                                                |
+----+------------------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here the statement that causing trouble:

```
select count(*) into @discard from `information_schema`.`PARTITIONS`
```

I have +-10 databases totaling over 8gb of data.

Is there any configuration to disable this query on system booting ? If yes, why run it during boot ?

**Information**

I have a standard MySQL installation without custom configs.

Best regards.

Comment: If you run the slow query in questio what's the execution time you get back? What's the result of the count? (ie how many tables do you have?)

Comment: Hi Erik, the result of query is: '4955' (36.40 sec)

Comment: Counting manualy, the total of tables in all databases is 5000...this query counts number of tables ? What can i do to reduce/stop this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems Debian, whose Linux Mint is based upon, have scripts that get executed when the mysql server is started or restarted, to check for corrupted tables and make an alert for that.

In my Debian server, the culprit seems to be `/etc/mysql/debian-start` bash script, which in turn calls `/usr/share/mysql/debian-start.inc.sh` , so check both scripts and comment out the function that is iterating all your tables, from a quick look it seems the following:

```
check_for_crashed_tables;
```

which is called from the `debian-start` script I mentioned above.

Comment: Nelson, perfectly! I'm was commented this argument and works fine here! ;) Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you could fix it :-)

Comment: From +- 3 minutes to less than 1 minute to start my station ;D #nice #nice

Comment: +1 same on ubuntu ... I have more than 21 gb of database on my Magento local DEV enviroment and when I start mysql first 5 minute I have a lot of `io wa`, commenting above line save me every morning when I start to work :)